# Entity Famework Data Service as a Windows Service how to change maxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: c#, dataservice

I'm trying to increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize` for my DataService. I've tried the solutions from these places:

- https://malvinly.com/2011/05/09/wcf-data-services-and-maxreceivedmessagesize/
- [How do I setup config files for WCF Data Service (odata) with EF 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664086/how-do-i-setup-config-files-for-wcf-data-service-odata-with-ef-6)

and some other places I can't remember but I can't get it working. The DataService is not running for a Web Application but in a Windows Service. The `app.config` is currently looking like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="Test"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="Test" maxBufferSize="10485760" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="10485760" maxStringContentLength="10485760"
        maxArrayLength="10485760" maxBytesPerRead="10485760" maxNameTableCharCount="10485760" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the app.config content... Still can't figure out how this should be done.

**EDIT**

As recommended I've also set the `readerQuotas` without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while we've found a solution...

Initially we took the `DataServiceHost` class to host our Service which does not support these options. After using `WebServiceHost` to host the service it worked:

```
WebServiceHost webServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(EfoDataService), new Uri[] { });

//Https binding
WebHttpBinding httpsbinding = new WebHttpBinding()
{
    Security = { Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport },
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2097152,
    MaxBufferSize = 2097152,
    MaxBufferPoolSize = 2097152,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
};

//adding https endPoint 
webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IRequestHandler), httpsbinding, secureBaseAddress);
```

It's a bit strange though since `DataServiceHost` does derive from `WebServiceHost`.